# pipenv FLASK_APP problems pointing inside folder

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

I've been trying to follow a few tutorials and start a flask project inside a pipenv environment.  I can't seem to point my export FLASK_APP=<-app.py location-> to the right location.

I start the project with `pipenv install flask`
I verified that python is working inside the environment:

If I put the app.py in the main VENV folder, I can point to it with `export FLASK_APP=app.py` and run `pipenv run flask run` and everything works fine.

I then create a folder called flask, with `__init__.py` and `app.py`.

I then try and export the FLASK_APP and run `pipenv run flask run`

`export FLASK_APP=/flask/app.py` does not work

`export FLASK_APP=./flask/app.py` does not work

`export FLASK_APP=$VIRTUAL_ENV/../flask/app.py` does not work

I can't even see the folder when I look in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/`.  I just see `bin/     include/ lib/     src/`

This has got to be something simple that I am missing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just use absolute path, or directly use `python app.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't put anything in virtual environment folder
- think of virtual environment folder as a black box managed by `pip` and `pipenv` commands.

here are steps to create flask app in pipenv

1. `mkdir <project_root>` make new folder for project
2. `cd <test_flask_app>` go into new folder
3. `pipenv --three` create new virtual environment using with python 3
4. `pipenv shell` activate pipenv virtual environment
5. `pipenv install flask` install flask
6. `mkdir <python_code_root>` create folder for all python code (see here for example python project https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod)
7. create simple flask app file `<python_code_root>/app.py` (taken from http://flask.pocoo.org/)

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       return "Hello World!"
   ```

   the expected project folder should look like

   ```
   .
   ├── Pipfile
   ├── Pipfile.lock
   └── <python_code_root>
       └── app.py
   ```
8. `export FLASK_APP=<python_code_root>/app.py` export variable
9. `flask run` start flask app
10. in browser go to http://localhost:5000/

---

Note that `pipenv --three` generates the python virtual env folder in a random hashed folder.  You're not supposed to manually edit/add anything in this folder.

When I run `pipenv --three` the output is:

```
   Creating a virtualenv for this project…
   Pipfile:
   /Users/grahamcrowell/Documents/test_flask_app/Pipfile
   Using /usr/local/bin/python3 (3.7.1) to create virtualenv…
   ✔ Complete 
   Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
   New python executable in /Users/grahamcrowell/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_flask_app-l4aYsVUB/bin/python3.7
   Also creating executable in /Users/grahamcrowell/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_flask_app-l4aYsVUB/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
   Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
   Virtualenv location:        /Users/grahamcrowell/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_flask_app-l4aYsVUB
   Creating a Pipfile for this project…
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I was trying to do:  `pipenv run flask run` .  Not sure why sometimes you have to put `pipenv run` before some commands, and others you don't.  I